# Vimeo screen sharing that the play and stop feature is done by one user

Tags: web-apps, javascript, php, web

I am looking for a script that would allow for video sharing on Vimeo where start and stop are being controlled by one admin account. Sort of like Netflix Party or Watch2gether. Would appreciate any leads.